# Swift Dictionary Taking Long Time to Compile

Tags: swift

I have a Realm closure that I use to update rows that have been changed:

```
try realm.write {

                  realm.create(Product.self, value: ["itemgroup": item.itemgroup,
                                                     "itembrand": item.itembrand,
                                                     "itemtype": item.itemtype,
                                                     "itemsubtype": item.itemsubtype,
                                                     "basedescription": item.basedescription,
                                                     "info": item.info,
                                                     "upc": item.upc,
                                                     "upc2": item.upc2,
                                                     "upc3": item.upc3,
                                                     "upc4": item.upc4,
                                                     "upc5": item.upc5,
                                                     "baseprice": item.baseprice,
                                                     "proprice": item.proprice,
                                                     "retailprice": item.retailprice,
                                                     "stdprice": item.stdprice,
                                                     "caseqty": item.caseqty,
                                                     "spord": item.spord,
                                                     "category": item.category,
                                                     "categorycode": item.categorycode,
                                                     "allowinbc": item.allowinbc,
                                                     "allowinab": item.allowinab], update: true)
                }
```

However, it's taking almost 10 minutes to compile!

Here is my model class:

```
class Product: Object {

    dynamic var itemno: String = ""
    dynamic var itemgroup: String = ""
    dynamic var itembrand: String = ""
    dynamic var itemtype: String = ""
    dynamic var itemsubtype: String = ""
    dynamic var basedescription: String = ""
    dynamic var info: String = ""
    dynamic var upc: String = ""
    dynamic var upc2: String = ""
    dynamic var upc3: String = ""
    dynamic var upc4: String = ""
    dynamic var upc5: String = ""
    dynamic var baseprice: Double = 0.00
    dynamic var proprice: Double = 0.00
    dynamic var retailprice: Double = 0.00
    dynamic var stdprice: Double = 0.00
    dynamic var caseqty: Int = 0
    dynamic var spord: String = ""
    dynamic var category: String = ""
    dynamic var categorycode: String = ""
    dynamic var allowinbc: String = ""
    dynamic var allowinab: String = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "itemno"
    }

    convenience init(itemno: String, itemgroup: String, itembrand: String, itemtype: String, itemsubtype: String, basedescription: String, info: String, upc: String, upc2: String, upc3: String, upc4: String, upc5: String, baseprice: Double, proprice: Double, retailprice: Double, stdprice: Double, caseqty: Int, spord: String, category: String, categorycode: String, allowinbc: String, allowinab: String) {

        self.init()
        self.itemno = itemno
        self.itemgroup = itemgroup
        self.itembrand = itembrand
        self.itemtype = itemtype
        self.itemsubtype = itemsubtype
        self.basedescription = basedescription
        self.info = info
        self.upc = upc
        self.upc2 = upc2
        self.upc3 = upc3
        self.upc4 = upc4
        self.upc5 = upc5
        self.baseprice = baseprice
        self.proprice = proprice
        self.retailprice = retailprice
        self.stdprice = stdprice
        self.caseqty = caseqty
        self.spord = spord
        self.category = category
        self.categorycode = categorycode
        self.allowinbc = allowinbc
        self.allowinab = allowinab
    }

}
```

What can I do to my code that will speed up compilation?

Thanks.

Comment: In your example code, what is the type of `item`?

Comment: @idz ``item`` is of type ``Product``, my model class. It's a constant that holds an instance of ``Product`` instantiated with the convenience initializer.

Comment: Almost perfectly answered by https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/26/swift-long-compile-time/

Comment: @BallpointBen Thank you. I wish I'd saw this article before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a 'best' answer in here since all the answers are very helpful. The fastest way for a large, Swift dictionary to compile is to not let the compiler infer the type of ***anything***. That means you need to define the data type of every item in the dictionary (including the dictionary itself).

The fastest way my dictionary compiled was:

```
try realm.write {

              let dict: [String: Any] = ["itemgroup": item.itemgroup as String,
                                         "itembrand": item.itembrand as String,
                                         "itemtype": item.itemtype as String,
                                         "itemsubtype": item.itemsubtype as String,
                                         "basedescription": item.basedescription as String,
                                         "info": item.info as String,
                                         "upc": item.upc as String,
                                         "upc2": item.upc2 as String,
                                         "upc3": item.upc3 as String,
                                         "upc4": item.upc4 as String,
                                         "upc5": item.upc5 as String,
                                         "baseprice": item.baseprice as Double,
                                         "proprice": item.proprice as Double,
                                         "retailprice": item.retailprice as Double,
                                         "stdprice": item.stdprice as Double,
                                         "caseqty": item.caseqty as Int,
                                         "spord": item.spord as String,
                                         "category": item.category as String,
                                         "categorycode": item.categorycode,
                                         "allowinbc": item.allowinbc as String,
                                         "allowinab": item.allowinab as String]

              realm.create(Product.self, value: dict, update: true)
            }
```

Comment: Do the `as` statements significantly speed up compilation?

Comment: Yes, @BallpointBen. After doing that, the compile time of the dictionary falls under 10 milliseconds!

Comment: I don't doubt that you're right. But... geez. Why does the compiler even care about the types of the values in a dictionary with `Any` values? I hope it's not wasting time checking the values for a subtype relation with `Any`...

Comment: @BallpointBen it most likely is checking for subtypes. I tried defining the dictionary type only without using ``as <Type>`` for each item and it took a ridiculous amount of time to compile...

Comment: So I guess we can conclude the following: Swift checks each value for subtype relation with the type of the dictionary's `Value`. With only `as`, it must find a type that all values belong to. With only `[String: Any]`, it must check that each value's (inferred) type is a subtype of `Any` -- a pointless check, but that must be what it's doing. With both `as` and `[String: Any]`, it checks that the `as` cast is allowed (easy), and then check that the cast type is a subtype of `Any` (easy). I just don't understand why it doesn't have a special case to always accept a type being treated as `Any`.

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I'm glad my answer helped! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this bug with creating large dictionaries. One option is to create and then mutate the dictionary in multiple steps:

```
var dict: [String: Any] = ["itemgroup": item.itemgroup]
dict["itembrand"] = item.itembrand
// Populate rest of dictionary as above

try realm.write {
    realm.create(Product.self, value: dict)
}
```

Comment: This won't work in this case. If `item.itemGroup` is a `String`, the dictionary type will be inferred to `[String: String]`. Then it won't be possible to add the `Double` value, e.g. `baseprice`.

Comment: Good point. Explicitly declaring the type is an easy enough fix.

Comment: You should use `Any` instead of `AnyObject` otherwise you will get a warning on every value type and you will have to cast it (e.g. `as NSString` or `as AnyObject`) to silence it.

Answer (score 1):

99% of problems with slow compiling in Swift are related to type inferring. This is most visible in complicated expressions (when the compiler has to search too many possibilities) or when creating a large dictionary from distinct types.

As a workaround, you can always turn the type inferring off by specifying the expected type, e.g.:

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = [
   "itemgroup": item.itemgroup,
   ...
]
realm.create(Product.self, value: dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not with Realm; it's the Swift compiler. It has a hard time compiling large dictionaries. Since `item` is already of type `Product` you could add it to the realm directly (but you said it was constant so this might involve some structural changes to your code).

Another option is to replace the body of your write block with:

```
let p = Product(value: item)
realm.add(p)
```

Comment: I have ``realm.add()`` in an if statement. The code shown in my question is inside the else block. If the item doesn't exist, it will be added with ``realm.add()``, else, if the item info from my API is different from the info stored on the device, the item is updated with ``realm.create()``

Comment: If it's an update use `realm.add(p, update: true)`, but beware for an update you must supply the primary key.